# What's the best way to display data when user input changes in Meteor (datepicker)?

Tags: meteor

I don't know how else to word this, but basically I'm implementing a datepicker, so the user can choose the range for which the data is displayed. The user picks a start data and ending date and with that, I re-run a gigantic function that is located in the `lib` folder to re-run and change all the data that is displayed via Meteor helpers on the main page.

The dates that the user picks are stored in Session variables, which are accessed in the function that I intended. The function runs, but no changes are displayed on client (but these changes are true in the console and I can see the changes being made via `console.log` statements I have throughout the function).

This is what the datepicker's onRendered function looks like:

```
Template.dashboard.onRendered(function(){
  // Date picker
  $(function() {

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

      var startDate = start.format('MMMM D, YYYY');
      Session.set("startingDate", startDate)
      var endDate = end.format('MMMM D, YYYY');
      Session.set("endingDate", endDate);
    }

  var firstDate = dates[0];
  var lastItem = dates.length-1;
  var lastDate = dates[lastItem]
    cb(moment(firstDate), moment(lastDate));

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        ranges: {
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

});

  });
```

The Tracker.autorun:

```
  Tracker.autorun(function(){
    libFxn();
  });
```

`libFxn()` is the rather large function in the lib folder that I call in the Tracker. So, whenever one of the Session variable changes due to user input, the `Tracker.autorun` fires and function is run and values are being changed, which I am able to see via console. However, on client, I don't see the changes.

That leaves me in a dilemma: I need to show the user the resulting data changes based on the input, but:

1) Changes are not seen in client, even though function in lib folder is being executed.
2) I can't use `document.location.reload(true);` or refresh the page in any way because when the page refreshes, the session variables are restored to default values (which is first date and last date of the `dates` array that I have on hand).

So I need to figure out a way to send the user's date input data to the function in the lib folder in a way that will show the changes in the client/template that doesn't involve Sessions if the page has to be refreshed.

If anyone can give me hints or tips, I would be grateful.

Here is an example of one helper, which is basically identical to all others minus the different variables it calls (all these variables are in the `libFxn()` function and are populated there and called via these helper functions):

```
  WinRate: function(){
    if(Number((((wins/gamesPlayed))))){
      return numeral((wins/gamesPlayed)).format('0%');
    } else if(Number((((wins/gamesPlayed)))) === 0){
      return "0%"
    } else{
      return "n/a";
    }
  }
```

Comment: On the persistence side of things if updating a collection is not an option, look at using one of the reactive localstorage packages and pushing the data into the HTML5 localstorage layer would let you persist it across page reloads.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was able to save the dates in a MongoDB collection, then call them in the lib function and everything worked fine. I used `document.location.reload(true);` to refresh the page and render the data. However, the only thing that sucks right now is that it looks really poverty and I'll have to find a way to make this look smoother and more "reactive."

Comment: How are your template and helpers set up, can you show them here or in a repo?

Comment: My helpers are basically just helpers that call variables that are calculated inside the function in the lib folder. I'll leave one example in my OP, but they are all like that in the sense that they call or manipulate variables that are calculated inside the function in the lib folder itself. As the template, it's a standard template with a custom design and all the helpers are inserted via `{{Blaze}}`. I think theoretically, it should be rendering the changes.

Comment: Do you make the variables reactive in any way? or are they just variables declared in the file?

Comment: @PhilipPryde They are just regular global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments above you are not making the variables themselves reactive. You can do this using the `Tracker.Dependency`.

In your lib file you will want to use `globalsDep = new Tracker.Dependency;` or similar, you will probably want to have one for each type of outcome from your function i.e. if you can modify 10 variables independently then you will want 10, a new dependency for each one otherwise you will re-run every helper that depends on them each time any value changes. if you want everything to re-run of course just use one:

`globalsDep = new Tracker.Dependency;`

Each place you modify the relevant variable (or at the end of your function if you only want one dependency) you need to tell the dependency that it has become invalid and needs to recompute

`globalsDep.changed();`

And then in each of the helpers you want to rerun you call the depends function:

`globalsDep.depends()`

And you should see them running straight away in the view. Simple example below:

```
/****************
** In Lib File **
****************/
globalsDep = new Tracker.Dependency;
xDep = new Tracker.Dependency;

x = 15;
y = 10;
t = 0;

myBigLongFunction = function(){
  x = x + 5;
  y = y + 1;
  t = x + y;

  console.log('Changing Values', x, y, t);
  globalsDep.changed();

  if (x > 20)
    xDep.changed();
}

/****************
** In JS File **
****************/
Template.main.helpers({
    testGlobalReactive: function(){
      globalsDep.depend();
      console.log('All vars rerun');
      return {t:t, x:x, y:y};
    },
    testXReactive: function(){
      xDep.depend();
      console.log('X rerun');
      return x;
    }
});

/****************
** In HTML File **
****************/
<template name="main">
  <div style="min-height:200px;width:100%;background-color:lightgrey;">
    {{#with testGlobalReactive}}
      X:{{x}}<br><br>
      Y:{{y}}<br><br>
      T:{{t}}<br><br>
    {{/with}}
    X Individual: {{testXReactive}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Although I would caution against having client state in this way, you would be better leveraging the reactivity of collections and ensuring everything is synched with the server through them, having this sort of data stored on the client will not be persistent anywhere and cannot be trusted in any manner as client can modify global variables at will. If you are already setting this data from collections in the function ignore the last but you may still want to consider accessing the data either in iron router data field or at a template level direct from collection as it will be reactive by default without need for the Tracker.dependency :D

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tens of thousands of lines of code and hundreds of variables, so placing all the information into collections right now is not feasible (maybe in the future when I refactor the code). The data rendering, in my experience, is faster this way and obviously uses less MongoDB storage.

Comment: Fair enough, that would be a lot of work! hope it helped anyway